# Parameterized Unit Tests in Scala (with JUnit4)

Tags: unit-testing, scala, junit, junit4

Is there a way to implement a **parameterized unit test** with *Scala*? Currently I use JUnit4 in the rest of my programs and I would like to continue using only "standard" APIs.

I found an example for [Junit4 with Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+JUnit+4+with+Groovy), but I have problems defining the `static` parts. Could be, because I am also quite new with *Scala* :-)

I am currently as fas as

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Assert._

import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters

@RunWith(classOf[Parameterized])
class MyTest extends junit.framework.TestCase {

    @Parameters object data {
        ...
    }

    @Parameter ...

    @Test
    def testFunction() = {
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's quite a nuisance, but it works. Two important things I discovered: companion object must come **after** test class, the function returning the parameters must return a collection of arrays of **AnyRef** (or Object). arrays of Any won't work. That the reason I use java.lang.Integer instead of Scala's Int.

```
import java.{util => ju, lang => jl}
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters

@RunWith(value = classOf[Parameterized])
class JUnit4ParameterizedTest(number: jl.Integer) {
    @Test def pushTest = println("number: " + number)
}

// NOTE: Defined AFTER companion class to prevent:
// Class com.openmip.drm.JUnit4ParameterizedTest has no public
// constructor TestCase(String name) or TestCase()
object JUnit4ParameterizedTest {

    // NOTE: Must return collection of Array[AnyRef] (NOT Array[Any]).
    @Parameters def parameters: ju.Collection[Array[jl.Integer]] = {
        val list = new ju.ArrayList[Array[jl.Integer]]()
        (1 to 10).foreach(n => list.add(Array(n)))
        list
    }
}
```

The output should be as expected:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
number: 1
number: 2
number: 3
number: 4
number: 5
number: 6
number: 7
number: 8
number: 9
number: 10
```

Comment: perfect! will try it out soon!

Comment: I did define the Paraterized Class after the companion class.. but it shows the error: `No public static parameters method on class `. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably better off with ScalaTest or Specs. The latter definitely supports parameterized tests, and is widely used in the Scala community. JUnit's syntax for parameterized tests is pretty horrible, and its reliance on static declarations won't make your task easier in Scala (probably you need a companion object).